# Tesseract works for images that contains only and only text- Crop image to get only the text part from image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ocr, tesseract

Tesseract works for images that contains only and only text. But what if there is text and image and we want to get only text to be recognized.

I am using Tesseract for OCR recognition of text from image. Tesseract is giving exact text from the images that are having only text in them. However when I checked the image that contains car and its car number, Tesseract gave different garbled text for the car number. I applied gray scale optimization, threshold and other effects to get the exact text output and to increase the accuracy of the output but it still giving different text mixed with different encoding. For the same, I am looking for other ways to extract such text.

Can anyone know that how to get text from such images using Tesseract OCR or any alternative so that only text part remains in image so that Tesseract can give the exact text in output.

To crop the image is one alternative to get the only text but how to do that using ImageMagick or any other option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you know exactly where on the image the text is, you can send along with the image the coordinates of those regions to Tesseract for recognition. Take a look at Tesseract API method `TesseractRect` or `SetRectangle`.

Comment: Your reply is worth considering although I want a more alternate way to detect text from image by any OCR means although I checked GOCR/JOCR, OCRopus and Tesseract but they have the same problem. But how about if you don't know where the text is on image as it is probably be taken from camera just like recognizing car number from cars.